# sqlalchemy equvalent of sql syntax

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a sql code that will print out all events that user with id=3 did not join particular yet:

```
SELECT * from Event where id not in (select event_id from Participant where user_id =3);
```

I want to write it in SQLAlchemy and so far I've got this

```
Event.query.filter(not_(Participant.user_id==3))
```

but produced query is not what I initially wrote:

```
SELECT "Event".id AS "Event_id",
"Event".name AS "Event_name",
"Event".published AS "Event_published",
"Event".published_when AS "Event_published_when",
"Event".published_by AS "Event_published_by"
FROM "Event", "Participant"
WHERE "Participant".user_id != ?
```

The above is not giving any results. I guess I wrote this SQLAlchemy query incorrectly. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
sub = Participant.query(Participant.event_id).filter(Participant.user_id==3)
res = Event.query.filter(Event.id.notin_(sub))
```

or maybe this way:

```
res = Session.query(Event, Participant).filter(Event.id == Participant.user_id).filter(Participant.user_id == 3)
```

Comment: @SuperShoot yeap! I think you're correct. Thanks for the notice

Comment: thanks for your input! Unfortunatelly, both solutions were incorrect due to problems with subquery (returned more than 1 record) so I had to modify it a bit. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax:

```
Event.query.filter(Event.id.notin_(db.session.query(Participant.event_id).filter(Participant.user_id==session['uid'])))
```

Subquery had to be limited to **event_id** only. Thanks to this it will now return correct data from DB.